# How to get current date with custom hour?

Tags: java

I need to get actual date with custom hour so I create this code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());

Calendar output = Calendar.getInstance();
output.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 1, 0);
output.getTime();
```

I hope it works but it seems a litle bit complicated.

Is there some other way how to get date with custom hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some other way how to get date with custom hour ?

Personally I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead:

```
// Ideally use an injectable clock...
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
// If this is effectively constant, extract it to a final static field
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(1, 0);

// Or use toDateTime(...) depending on what you're trying to accomplish
LocalDateTime todayAtTime = today.toLocalDateTime(time);
```

Joda Time has a *much* more pleasant API than `java.util.{Date, Calendar}`

Comment: @hudi: Well, I had a typo of a variable name. Not really a syntax error... anyway, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, your_custom_hour);
your_custom_hour : 0-23
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than use Joda time I'd do it slightly cleaner:

```
 int hour = 1;
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

`Calendar.getInstance()` returns the current date and time anyway so `setTime(new Date())` is unnecessary.

Comment: The Calendar guys posted in order of precision that they reset! :-)